Запуск AutoClickera по нажатию на клавишу Python Tkinter
Я написал AutoClicker со своей GUI на Tkinter, я создал две кнопки которые по нажатию включали или отключали кликер. Также в GUI есть окно для регулировки скорости. Но я также  пытался добавить такую функцию в кликер что бы можно было нажимать на клавиши клавиатуры ('z', 'x') что бы включать или отключать кликер, реализовать пытался через библиотеку keyboard. Но как видно у меня не получилось. Хотелось бы попросить помощи. Вот сам код.

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
import keyboard
import pyautogui
import time

clicking = True
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True

root = Tk()
root.title('.AutoClicker.')
root.geometry('350x250')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.attributes('-topmost', True)


def Start_Clicker():
    global clicking
    click_timer = input_click.get()
    while clicking or keyboard.is_pressed('z'):
        time.sleep(float(click_timer))
        pyautogui.tripleClick()
        root.update()
    clicking = True


keyboard.add_hotkey('z', Start_Clicker)


def Stop_Clicker():
    global clicking
    clicking = False
    root.update()


keyboard.add_hotkey('x', Stop_Clicker)


def Info():
    showinfo(title="Информация", message="Это AutoClicker написанный на Python \n Для связи с разработчиком пишите в Discord: artemka8679")


Click_Button = ttk.Button(text='Старт', command=Start_Clicker)
Click_Button.place(x=65, y=150, height=65, width=85)

Click_Button = ttk.Button(text='Стоп', command=Stop_Clicker)
Click_Button.place(x=195, y=150, height=65, width=85)

info_Button = ttk.Button(text='информация', command=Info)
info_Button.place(x=140, y=0,)

text_label = ttk.Label(text='Укажите скорость клика к примеру такую как 0.1, 0.01 ')
text_label.place(x=45, y=30)

input_click = ttk.Entry()
input_click.place(x=95, y=50, height=20, width=160)

root.mainloop()


